# Is "found himself in hot water with the local council" a metaphor? If yes, what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=251) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> In 2013, Grylls found himself in hot water with the local council after erecting a huge
>   metal slide that ended with a drop off a cliff face into the sea below.

I understand the latter part, a huge metal slide.

the question is,

Is "found himself in hot water with the local council" a metaphor? If yes, what does that mean?

Comment: As the answer below explains, it is an idiom. But it is technically a metaphor too. "Trouble" is here conceptualized as hot water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/idiom).

*To find oneself in hot water* means to be in trouble, as stated in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/be-in-hot-water) dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does "with the local council" part mean that local council gives him some difficulties?

Comment: Most likely, given that he was in hot water. I read that off as "he was in trouble with local authorities". And if my answer is helpful, please accept it by clicking on the check symbol next to it. =)